# Unity - black windows when gaining focus

Tags: unity, 13.04

I'm using Ubuntu13.04+Unity and, from time to time when I switch between windows, the one that gains focus goes bananas, and it's rendered completely black. This happens randomly with any application (Skype, pidgin, etc.) when its window is not maximized.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072206

So far no progress.
Make sure to click "This bug affects me" on the bug report in order to increase visibility.

Comment: Thanks! It's sad to know that this bug has been around for quite a while.